# Email Validation / confirmation

Tags: c#, email-validation, email-confirmation

I have a web application that anyone can sign up using their email address (anything@anydomain.any) without confirming/validating the email address. I would like to know if there is any third party service or an API for C# to validate the email address or send them confirmation to proceed with registration.

Comment: What did Google tell you?

Comment: This is something you should do yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you use asp.net identity, this is handled for you, out of box, you just need to plug your email configuration and everything just works.

You can also customize the template of the messages

More info: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity

In case you are implementing the sign-up and login yourself, I strongly suggest you to use a famous library, and self implemented security code is almost always packed with mistakes.

In case you are using an older security implementation by Microsoft, like Asp.Net membership or simple membership, I guess you need to implement Email confirmation yourself which is not too difficult by the way.

You need to create a random code, put it in the link, and save it in the database, then in the page serving the link you get the code and verify the account associated with that code.